# What associates this ng-view with a controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm not seeing how my div ng-view in my index.html is associated with PhoneListCtrl.
For example, how would I associate it with PhoneDetailCtrl?

My index.html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

js/controllers.js:

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
}]);

 phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.phones = data;
});
$scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```

My app.js:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
      'ngRoute',
      'phonecatControllers'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/phones', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
                controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'

}).when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
}).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
});
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure $routeProvider inside app.js you have

`controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'` and `controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'`